# Mobile detection code

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile

Is is possible to have a code in a web link that detects what mobile platform a user is on eg iPhone/iPad, Andriod, Blackberry etc...

I'm trying to solve a problem at the app company I work at where whenever we do a tweet we include a call to action - a bitly link with the app download link. However because the app is on the Apple app store, Google Play store and Blackberry store we have to do 3 different bitly links to different app stores.

What I want to create is code to detect what platform a user is on and build that into a shortened url. So when we do a tweet, we just do one link and it automatically directs the user to the appropriate app store depending on what device they are using.

Does this exist already? If not how can it be created? Please give me some insights/ideas as to how this could be achieved

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the which device user is on by using

`var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();`

Comment: Thanks but is this possible to be built into a shortened URL? The idea I'm toying with is creating my own bitly link but with this code built into it so with one click of the link, the user will be taken to the appropriate app store.

Comment: @Charlie: Sorry but i didnt get your point `is this possible to be built into a shortened URL`

Comment: Ok I'll paint a picture... On Twitter bitly liks are common to guide users to external sources be it web pages or in my case we use bitly links as a 'call to action' to direct the user to the app store to download it. However, I'm looking to essentially create my own bitly shortened url so whenever it is clicked on the Mobile detection code activates while the page loads and directs you to the appropriate app store to download. The transition needs to be seamless so there's one click and you're in the appropriate app store for your platform. Does that help?

Comment: @Deepesh answer correct to use userAgent. In JavaScript create a subString from the result of var userAgent and use a switch statement to point to a url!!